# Publish method doesn't work properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an `Entry` model with a boolean column `published`, which is set to `false` by default. I wrote the following method in the model:

```
def self.publish
  self.update(published: true)
end
```

and in my controller I have

```
def publish
  @entry = Entry.find(params[:id]
  @entry.publish
  redirect_to entries_path
end
```

(I thought to make it similar to the calling of `destroy` method in the model). Finally, in my view I have this:

```
<%= link_to "Publish", entries_path, method: :publish %>
```

But when I click the link, the request is processed by `create` method and returns me the following error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in Multiflora::EntriesController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: entry
```

Comment: You are doing a lot of wrong things here. Have you added `publish` to your routes ? Kindly post your `routes.rb`.

Comment: @dkp I see.. may be there's another way to set that boolean value to true without this reinventing the wheel? @_@

Comment: First of all you need to understand what is a `method` passed in `link_to` . It is an HTTP request to be made i.e it can be a `post` or `put` or `delete` or `get` (default). You have assigned `method: :publish` which is wrong, it should be `method: :put` since you are trying to update. Secondly your route `entries_path` should point to `publish` action of your controller. And, lastly `publish` should be an **instance method** in your model. Currently, it is a class method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers, I've figured out what was my mistake, but I took a little think and decided to make it much more simple: I just added a checkbox to edit form, that sets `:published` attribute of entry true. Here it is:

```
<%=form_for(@entry, as: :entry, url: content_entry_path(@entry)) do |f| %>
  # ...
  <p>
    <%= f.label "Publish" %> <br />
    <%= f.hidden_field :published, value: '' %>
    <%= f.check_box :published, checked: true %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Anyways a lot of thanks for your answers! That was my lack of knowledge and I'll remember what have I done wrong

Comment: You might want to remove the `hidden_field`

Answer (score 1):

First thing, there is no HTTP method called `:publish` it should be `:put` or `:patch`

Second you need to pass id as parameter

```
<%= link_to "Publish", publish_entry_path(@entry) %>
```

Also you will need to add route for publish action

```
resources :events do
  member do
    put :publish
  end
end
```

`publish` method should be instance method

```
def publish 
  self.update(published: true) 
end
```

Comment: thanks! but I think I've just figured out a simplier way to manage that. I'll post it here as an answer

Answer (score 1):

The method is wrong in link_to as per the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html) so you have to mention one of valid Http methods (patch preferred in your case) , and then edit your route.rb file to transfer this patch request to your specified function like this:

```
patch'/entries/publish', to: 'entries#publish'
```

then change the "entries_path" to "entry_path"

so link code should look like this:

```
<%= link_to "Publish", entry_path, method: :patch%>
```